# Can I shift and then move to escape?

Tags: dnd-4e, movement, shift

Can I shift away from an enemy and then use a move action to get farther away from them without provoking an attack of opportunity?

Answer (score 19):

**Yes**, if at the end of the shift you are not on a threatened square.

Shift is a move action that lets you move 1 square without provoking opportunity attacks. You can then convert your standard action to a move action in order to walk away your speed.

Note that some creatures may have a reach of 2 squares or more with their basic attacks. These creatures **still threaten only adjacent squares** unless they also have the **Threatening Reach** trait.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**

So long as you are not adjacent to an enemy nor within an enemy's threatening reach, you may move without penalty, even if that move is the result of converting a standard action into a move action.

Answer (score 3):

yes you can. You can use a move action to shift and trade your standard down for a move to take a full movement action.

Comment: Argh! 12 seconds!